# Is Microsoft UIP (User Interface Process Application Block for .NET) deprecated?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webforms

I'm trying to do some research for my company regarding Microsoft UIP. Basically, I've been tasked to understand the risks of using UIP. If what I've seen [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817680.aspx) is any indication, UIP is no longer supported by Microsoft:

> **Retired Content**
>   This content is outdated and is no longer being maintained. It is provided as a courtesy for individuals who are still using these technologies. This page may contain URLs that were valid when originally published, but now link to sites or pages that no longer exist.

I realize "Retired Content" is referring to the documentation itself, but I can't find updated documentation on UIP on MSDN.

So, has anybody seen any indication that UIP is no longer supported by Microsoft? If it is still technically supported, do we know if Microsoft is actively developing it?

Comment: What process did you follow that led you to that link? Whatever that process was, _don't do that again_. You're bound to find more ancient, obsolete texts, and to think that they are relevant.

Comment: I have my ways.  I have a PhD in Archeology.

Comment: Archeology is fine. Just don't use flint tools thinking they're the latest.

Comment: I was actually looking for evidence to *not* use UIP.  I honestly had never heard of it before until I found out about an application in my company that uses it.  I was not able to find much at all, which was a good indicator that it was not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That link is dated 2003!!!  It's safe to say that it is obsolete, supplanted by newer technologies.

http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/817259-uip-user-interface-process

> the UIP has been dead for years. I believe you can still get the
>   source. The enterprise blocks have a Web Client Software factory which
>   is the new MVC block. You could also switch to asp.net extensions MVC
>   library.